# componentWillReceiveProps called twice in react+redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

componentWillReceiveProps called twice in my below code. not sure why. how to prevent it by calling twice?

```
export class EmpSearch extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  Empnumber: ''
};
  this.updateEmpNumber = this.updateEmpNumber.bind(this);
}

updateEmpNumber(e) {
    this.props.dispatch({
            type: 'UPDATE_EMP_NUMBER',
            payload: e.target.value
        });
}

 render() {
return (
  <div className="row">
    <form>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="Empnumber">Emp Number</label>
        <input type="text" className="form-control" id="Empnumber" placeholder="Emp Number" value={this.state.Empnumber} onChange={this.updateEmpNumber.bind(this)}/>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
);
}
}

 function mapStateToProps(state){
return{
Empnumber: state.Empnumber
};
}

 export default connect(mapStateToProps)(EmpSearch);
```

Emp detals page are below where i am calling componentWillReceiveProps and in this i am calling an API and setting the state.

```
class EmpDetail extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {        
   super(props);
   this.state = {
 };


}

 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.GetData(nextProps);
}

 GetData(props){

 //Making and API call and Set the state

 }

render() {
    const empNumber = this.props.Empnumber;
    return (
        <div className="container">
            Empnumber = {empNumber}
        </div>
    );
  }
  }

function mapStateToProps(state){
 return {
    Empnumber: state.Empnumber
    }
  }

 export default connect(mapStateToProps)(EmpDetail);
```

Comment: why do you have `updateEmpNumber` method defined twice ?

Comment: No, I have defined only once as mentioned in the code.

Comment: You do have two `updateEmpNumber`

Comment: sorry, updated the above code... actually there is only one  updateEmpNumber in my code.

Answer (score 0):

-I dont undestand your project flow ,try to upload more files such as corresponding action.js and reducer.js.,points below might help....

1. making an api call in componentWillRecieveProps is not a right choice because this lifecycle hook runs more than one time ,whenever props are updated componentWillRecieveProps is called .
2. So Whenever mapStateToProps return state then componentWillRecieveProps is called ,So you will end up making multiple api calls which is not a correct way, performance wise .